# Update the apollo cache without calling the graphql server (apollo v3.3)

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I'm building a react app, I have a datasheet and update directly on the data stream
I want when I send data to graphql server for update and get `true` result then I will update apollo cache with `cache.writeQuery`

- The problem is that when the following code is executed, there is also a request to the graphql server to get the data from the whole table and update the cache, I don't want to request to the graphql server to work. There, I want to update from the browser. So where did I go wrong?

here is my code

```js
updateInventoryCache: async (_, { inventory, productId, variables }, { cache }) => {
      let variablesData;
      if (variables) {
        variablesData = JSON.parse(variables);
      }
      const { getListProduct } = cache.readQuery({
        query: GET_PAGING_PRODUCT,
        variables: variablesData.variables
      });
      cache.writeQuery({
        query: GET_PAGING_PRODUCT,
        variables: variablesData.variables,
        data: {
          getListProduct: {
            ...getListProduct,
            products: getListProduct.products.map((product) => {
              if (product.id === productId) {
                return {
                  ...product,
                  inventory
                };
              }
              return product;
            })
          }
        }
      });
      return true;
    }
```

"@apollo/client": "^3.3.7"

update 1:

I will initially call the graphql server to get the data and store it in apollo's (cache-and-network) cache. Then I want to update that data in the cache without having to call the apollo server to `refetchQueries` As in the post, I used the `client.writeQuery` function to update the cache but instead of updating at the client, apollo called the graphql server to get new data and update the cache while I was not using `refetchQueries`.

update 2:
I checked, my cache has been updated but my UI doesn't re-render

Answer (score 0):

Use `fetchPolicy="cache-only"` to use only the cache https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#setting-a-fetch-policy

Comment: No, this is not my mean.
I mean:
I will initially call the graphql server to get the data and store it in apollo's (cache-and-network) cache.
Then I want to update that data in the cache without having to call the apollo server to `refetchQueries`
As in the post, I used the `writeQuery` function to update the cache but instead of updating at the client, apollo called the graphql server to get new data and update the cache while I was not using` refetchQueries. `

Comment: cache-and-network will always update, so I know it first queries the current cache and then makes a request to the server to update the cache for the next query.

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/

Comment: I checked, my cache has been updated but my UI doesn't re-render :(

Comment: My cache knowledge only goes this far, but you can do it, don't get discouraged

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is `nextFetchPolicy="cache-first"`:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#usequery-api

> `nextFetchPolicy`
>
> FetchPolicy to begin enforcing
> after the current request. Useful for switching back to `cache-first`
> after `cache-and-network` or `network-only`.

After your call to `cache.writeQuery` your datasheet query will then check the `cache-first` to see if all of it's required data is there. If you get a cache hit, it will return data immediately without loading.

Keep in mind with AC3, sometimes multiple queries can share the same cache object but request different fields. If either `cache.writeQuery` or your `typePolicies` merge causes an active query field to be missing from the cache, it will result in a cache miss for that query. I.e. An active query that once had valid `data`, will suddenly return `undefined`. [More on that issue here.](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2678)